# How to pass a const variable from one component to another react

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-component

Hello I am trying to add Apollo to my react app and in the documentation it says to wrap you app in the `<ApolloProvider client={client}>` tag and pass client in as a variable like so:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import PageLayout from './components/page-layout'
import CreateApolloClient from './apollo-settings'
import { ApolloProvider } from '@apollo/react-hooks';
import ApolloClient from 'apollo-boost';
import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

    const client = new ApolloClient({
        uri: 'http://localhost/headless-cms/admin/',
        fetchOptions: {
            mode: 'no-cors',
        },
    });


ReactDOM.render(<ApolloProvider client={client}><BrowserRouter><PageLayout /></BrowserRouter></ApolloProvider>, document.getElementById('site-wrapper'));
```

However I want to remove the `const client` from the index.js page and move it into another template just to keep things organised like so:

```
import React from 'react';
import { ApolloProvider } from '@apollo/react-hooks';
import ApolloClient from 'apollo-boost';

const CreateApolloClient = () => {
    const client = new ApolloClient({
        uri: 'http://localhost/headless-cms/admin/',
        fetchOptions: {
            mode: 'no-cors',
        },
    });
}

export default CreateApolloClient;
```

What I am struggling with is when importing CreateApolloClient into the index.js page how do I then access the const client and pass it into the `<ApolloProvider client={client}>`

Thank you for any help in advanced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return the apollo client instance in your function and export the `createApolloClient`.

```
import { ApolloProvider } from '@apollo/react-hooks';
import ApolloClient from 'apollo-boost';

export const createApolloClient = () => {
    return new ApolloClient({
        uri: 'http://localhost/headless-cms/admin/',
        fetchOptions: {
            mode: 'no-cors',
        },
    });
}

export default CreateApolloClient;
```

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import PageLayout from './components/page-layout'
import {createApolloClient} from './apollo-settings'
import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import { ApolloProvider } from '@apollo/react-hooks';

const client = createApolloClient();

ReactDOM.render(<ApolloProvider client={client}><BrowserRouter><PageLayout /></BrowserRouter></ApolloProvider>, document.getElementById('site-wrapper'));
```